# iOS JSON Data Decodable

Tags: ios, json

I'd like to approach the json of each champion of Riot Games and get the data.
To do so, I approached json with information of all champions and brought approximate data of each champion.
But there was no data I wanted in it.
I found out that I have to approach each champion's detail json to get the data I want.
I was able to find out the URL of each champion using the id that I first brought.
But the decodable I've organized can only contain information from one champion. The number of champions in League of Legends is more than 150.
How can we solve this problem?
I've been spending two days on this...

```
    //MARK: 5. RiotUrl Json Parsing
    func didUpdataChampion(_ championManager: ChampionManager, champion: [ChampionRiot]) {
        print(#function)
        var count = 0
        var urlArray = [URL]()
        for data in champion {
            let id = data.id
            //JSON URL with data from all champions
            guard let url = URL(string: "https://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/11.16.1/img/champion/\(id).png") else { return }
            urlArray.append(url)
            ChampValue.nameArray.append(data.name)
            let championStats = "LV-1 기준 \n\n공격력:\(data.attackdamage)\n 공격속도:\(data.attackspeed)\n HP:\(data.hp)\n 방어력:\(data.armor)\n 마법저항력:\(data.spellblock)"
            ChampValue.statsd.append(championStats)
            ChampValue.idArray.append(id)
            let counterUrl = "https://www.op.gg/champion/\(id)/statistics"
            guard let safeCounterUrl = URL(string: counterUrl) else {
                print("safeCounterUrl--Error")
                return}
            ChampValue.counterIdArray.append(safeCounterUrl)
            // Use id to access each champion json
            let skillURLString = "https://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/11.16.1/data/en_US/champion/\(id).json"
            guard let skillURL = URL(string: skillURLString) else {
                print("urlError")
                return }
            let skillSession = URLSession(configuration: .default)
            let task = skillSession.dataTask(with: skillURL) { data, reponds, error in
                if error != nil {
                  print("errorSkillSession")
                    return
                }
                if let safeData = data {
                    self.skillDecode(safeData: safeData)
                }
        }
        task.resume()
        ChampValue.valueCount = urlArray.count
        ChampValue.arrayURL = urlArray
        getData()
    }
}
```

Each champion decodable function

```
    func skillDecode(safeData : Data ){
       let skilldecoder = JSONDecoder()
        do {
            let decoderData = try skilldecoder.decode(Champions.self, from: safeData)
            for datain in decoderData.data.ahri.id{
                print(datain)
        }
        }catch DecodingError.keyNotFound(let codingKey, let context){
            print(context.debugDescription)
            print(context.underlyingError)
        }catch DecodingError.typeMismatch(let type, let context) {
            print(type)
        }catch DecodingError.valueNotFound(let value, let context) {
            print(value)
        }catch {
            print("error")
        }
        
        
        
    }
```

My Decodable Struct
현재 이 코드는 에러를 이야기합니다.
저는 이유를 알고있습니다.
이유는

```
struct DataClass: Codable {
      let ahri: Ahri

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case ahri
    }
}
```

이부분 인거 같습니다.
코딩키 에 150개 이상의 챔피언들의 이름을 줄수 있는 방법이 있습니까?

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

// MARK: - Champions
struct Champions: Codable {
    let type, format, version: String
    let data: DataClass
}

// MARK: - DataClass
struct DataClass: Codable {
    let ahri: Ahri

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case ahri
    }
}

// MARK: - Ahri
struct Ahri: Codable {
    let id, key, name, title: String
    let image: CImage
    let skins: [Skin]
    let lore, blurb: String
    let allytips, enemytips, tags: [String]
    let partype: String
    let info: CInfo
    let stats: [String: statsValue]
    let spells: [Spell]
    let passive: Passive
    let recommended: [JSONAny]
}
struct statsValue : Codable {
    let intValue : Int
    let doubleValue : Double
}
// MARK: - Image
struct CImage: Codable {
    let full, sprite, group: String
    let x, y, w, h: Int
}

// MARK: - Info
struct CInfo: Codable {
    let attack, defense, magic, difficulty: Int
}

// MARK: - Passive
struct Passive: Codable {
    let name, passiveDescription: String
    let image: Image

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name
        case passiveDescription
        case image
    }
}

// MARK: - Skin
struct Skin: Codable {
    let id: String
    let num: Int
    let name: String
    let chromas: Bool
}

// MARK: - Spell
struct Spell: Codable {
    let id, name, spellDescription, tooltip: String
    let leveltip: Leveltip
    let maxrank: Int
    let cooldown: [Int]
    let cooldownBurn: String
    let cost: [Int]
    let costBurn: String
    let datavalues: Datavalues
    let effect: [[Double]?]
    let effectBurn: [String?]
    let vars: [JSONAny]
    let costType, maxammo: String
    let range: [Int]
    let rangeBurn: String
    let image: Image
    let resource: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, name
        case spellDescription
        case tooltip, leveltip, maxrank, cooldown, cooldownBurn, cost, costBurn, datavalues, effect, effectBurn, vars, costType, maxammo, range, rangeBurn, image, resource
    }
}

// MARK: - Datavalues
struct Datavalues: Codable {
}

// MARK: - Leveltip
struct Leveltip: Codable {
    let label, effect: [String]
}

// MARK: - Encode/decode helpers

class JSONNull: Codable, Hashable {

    public static func == (lhs: JSONNull, rhs: JSONNull) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    public var hashValue: Int {
        return 0
    }

    public init() {}

    public required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        if !container.decodeNil() {
            throw DecodingError.typeMismatch(JSONNull.self, DecodingError.Context(codingPath: decoder.codingPath, debugDescription: "Wrong type for JSONNull"))
        }
    }

    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        try container.encodeNil()
    }
}

class JSONCodingKey: CodingKey {
    let key: String

    required init?(intValue: Int) {
        return nil
    }

    required init?(stringValue: String) {
        key = stringValue
    }

    var intValue: Int? {
        return nil
    }

    var stringValue: String {
        return key
    }
}

class JSONAny: Codable {

    let value: Any

    static func decodingError(forCodingPath codingPath: [CodingKey]) -> DecodingError {
        let context = DecodingError.Context(codingPath: codingPath, debugDescription: "Cannot decode JSONAny")
        return DecodingError.typeMismatch(JSONAny.self, context)
    }

    static func encodingError(forValue value: Any, codingPath: [CodingKey]) -> EncodingError {
        let context = EncodingError.Context(codingPath: codingPath, debugDescription: "Cannot encode JSONAny")
        return EncodingError.invalidValue(value, context)
    }

    static func decode(from container: SingleValueDecodingContainer) throws -> Any {
        if let value = try? container.decode(Bool.self) {
            return value
        }
        if let value = try? container.decode(Int64.self) {
            return value
        }
        if let value = try? container.decode(Double.self) {
            return value
        }
        if let value = try? container.decode(String.self) {
            return value
        }
        if container.decodeNil() {
            return JSONNull()
        }
        throw decodingError(forCodingPath: container.codingPath)
    }

    static func decode(from container: inout UnkeyedDecodingContainer) throws -> Any {
        if let value = try? container.decode(Bool.self) {
            return value
        }
        if let value = try? container.decode(Int64.self) {
            return value
        }
        if let value = try? container.decode(Double.self) {
            return value
        }
        if let value = try? container.decode(String.self) {
            return value
        }
        if let value = try? container.decodeNil() {
            if value {
                return JSONNull()
            }
        }
        if var container = try? container.nestedUnkeyedContainer() {
            return try decodeArray(from: &container)
        }
        if var container = try? container.nestedContainer(keyedBy: JSONCodingKey.self) {
            return try decodeDictionary(from: &container)
        }
        throw decodingError(forCodingPath: container.codingPath)
    }

    static func decode(from container: inout KeyedDecodingContainer<JSONCodingKey>, forKey key: JSONCodingKey) throws -> Any {
        if let value = try? container.decode(Bool.self, forKey: key) {
            return value
        }
        if let value = try? container.decode(Int64.self, forKey: key) {
            return value
        }
        if let value = try? container.decode(Double.self, forKey: key) {
            return value
        }
        if let value = try? container.decode(String.self, forKey: key) {
            return value
        }
        if let value = try? container.decodeNil(forKey: key) {
            if value {
                return JSONNull()
            }
        }
        if var container = try? container.nestedUnkeyedContainer(forKey: key) {
            return try decodeArray(from: &container)
        }
        if var container = try? container.nestedContainer(keyedBy: JSONCodingKey.self, forKey: key) {
            return try decodeDictionary(from: &container)
        }
        throw decodingError(forCodingPath: container.codingPath)
    }

    static func decodeArray(from container: inout UnkeyedDecodingContainer) throws -> [Any] {
        var arr: [Any] = []
        while !container.isAtEnd {
            let value = try decode(from: &container)
            arr.append(value)
        }
        return arr
    }

    static func decodeDictionary(from container: inout KeyedDecodingContainer<JSONCodingKey>) throws -> [String: Any] {
        var dict = [String: Any]()
        for key in container.allKeys {
            let value = try decode(from: &container, forKey: key)
            dict[key.stringValue] = value
        }
        return dict
    }

    static func encode(to container: inout UnkeyedEncodingContainer, array: [Any]) throws {
        for value in array {
            if let value = value as? Bool {
                try container.encode(value)
            } else if let value = value as? Int64 {
                try container.encode(value)
            } else if let value = value as? Double {
                try container.encode(value)
            } else if let value = value as? String {
                try container.encode(value)
            } else if value is JSONNull {
                try container.encodeNil()
            } else if let value = value as? [Any] {
                var container = container.nestedUnkeyedContainer()
                try encode(to: &container, array: value)
            } else if let value = value as? [String: Any] {
                var container = container.nestedContainer(keyedBy: JSONCodingKey.self)
                try encode(to: &container, dictionary: value)
            } else {
                throw encodingError(forValue: value, codingPath: container.codingPath)
            }
        }
    }

    static func encode(to container: inout KeyedEncodingContainer<JSONCodingKey>, dictionary: [String: Any]) throws {
        for (key, value) in dictionary {
            let key = JSONCodingKey(stringValue: key)!
            if let value = value as? Bool {
                try container.encode(value, forKey: key)
            } else if let value = value as? Int64 {
                try container.encode(value, forKey: key)
            } else if let value = value as? Double {
                try container.encode(value, forKey: key)
            } else if let value = value as? String {
                try container.encode(value, forKey: key)
            } else if value is JSONNull {
                try container.encodeNil(forKey: key)
            } else if let value = value as? [Any] {
                var container = container.nestedUnkeyedContainer(forKey: key)
                try encode(to: &container, array: value)
            } else if let value = value as? [String: Any] {
                var container = container.nestedContainer(keyedBy: JSONCodingKey.self, forKey: key)
                try encode(to: &container, dictionary: value)
            } else {
                throw encodingError(forValue: value, codingPath: container.codingPath)
            }
        }
    }

    static func encode(to container: inout SingleValueEncodingContainer, value: Any) throws {
        if let value = value as? Bool {
            try container.encode(value)
        } else if let value = value as? Int64 {
            try container.encode(value)
        } else if let value = value as? Double {
            try container.encode(value)
        } else if let value = value as? String {
            try container.encode(value)
        } else if value is JSONNull {
            try container.encodeNil()
        } else {
            throw encodingError(forValue: value, codingPath: container.codingPath)
        }
    }

    public required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        if var arrayContainer = try? decoder.unkeyedContainer() {
            self.value = try JSONAny.decodeArray(from: &arrayContainer)
        } else if var container = try? decoder.container(keyedBy: JSONCodingKey.self) {
            self.value = try JSONAny.decodeDictionary(from: &container)
        } else {
            let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
            self.value = try JSONAny.decode(from: container)
        }
    }

    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        if let arr = self.value as? [Any] {
            var container = encoder.unkeyedContainer()
            try JSONAny.encode(to: &container, array: arr)
        } else if let dict = self.value as? [String: Any] {
            var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: JSONCodingKey.self)
            try JSONAny.encode(to: &container, dictionary: dict)
        } else {
            var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
            try JSONAny.encode(to: &container, value: self.value)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a sample of the json response(s) you're attempting to parse

Comment: http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/11.16.1/data/en_US/champion/Aatrox.json